# CS1026: ) Expected | CS1002: ; expected | CS1513: } expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
 private void Context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        if (context.Items[typeof(IServiceScope)] is IServiceScope scope)
        {
            scope.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

When I try to build my project (*Framework 4.7.2*) I am getting the

> : error CS1026: ) expected : error CS1002: ; expected : error CS1513:
>   } expected

On the line

```
if (context.Items[typeof(IServiceScope)] is IServiceScope scope)
```

But I don't see where it's throwing the error.

Comment: Check the C# version in the Build properties of your project. You're using "pattern matching", introduced in C# 7.

Comment: Was `obj is Scope scope` already implemented in _4.7.2_?

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda That's a language feature, not a .Net Framework feature

Comment: Pattern matching is a language feature introduced in C# 7 or later, not a .NET feature. The framework version doesn't matter.

Comment: go to the properties of your project then to [Build] then scroll down to the end and click [Advanced] then choose a C# [Language Version] that is higher than 7.0.

Comment: @phuzi You enlightened my life, I always thought I was stuck with C# 6 because I couldn't upgrade my framework!

Comment: My Language Version is C# latest major version (default)... I already tried one Version higher then 7.0. I tried C# 7.3 but then I get the error "invalid option '7.3' for /langversion; must be ISO-1,ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6"

Comment: Well using C# 7 is the solution. Research that error message. Also, which Visual Studio version do you use? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868803/error-invalid-option-6-for-langversion-must-be-iso-1-iso-2-3-4-5-or-defa

Comment: I had to update "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" ! No it's building... thanks for the help

Comment: @user1861065 you don't have to do that with Visual Studio 2019. Which version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped to update "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" over Nuget

now it builds without error.

Comment: You should also mention you had to change the C# version, so that your answer is complete.